# Fourier series of function $f(x)=0$ if $-\pi<x<0$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ if $0<x<\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, fourier-series

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }-\pi<x<0, \\
\sin(x) & \text{if }0<x<\pi.
\end{cases}$$

My attempt:

I went the route of expanding this function with a complex Fourier series.

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} C_{n}e^{inx}$$

$$C_{n} = \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} e^{-inx} \,\mathrm dx = \frac {1}{\pi}\left(\frac {1}{1-n^2}\right)$$

because only even $n$ terms survive, odd $n$ are 0

$$
C_0 = \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\, \mathrm dx = \frac {1}{\pi} 
$$

so

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac {1}{\pi} \left(\frac {e^{i2x}}{1-2^2} + \frac {e^{i4x}}{1-4^2}+\frac {e^{i6x}}{1-6^2}+\cdots\right) + \frac {1}{\pi} \left(\frac {e^{-i2x}}{1-2^2} + \frac {e^{-i4x}}{1-4^2}+\frac {e^{-i6x}}{1-6^2}+\cdots\right)
$$

In sine and cosine terms,

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac {2}{\pi} \left(\frac {\cos(2x)}{1-2^2} + \frac {\cos(4x)}{1-4^2}+\frac {\cos(6x)}{1-6^2}+\cdots\right)
$$

But the answer in my book is given as

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x)+ \frac {2}{\pi} \left(\frac {\cos(2x)}{2^2-1} + \frac {\cos(4x)}{4^2-1}+\frac {\cos(6x)}{6^2-1}+\dotsb\right)$$

I don't understand how there is a sine term and the denominator of the cosines has $-1$.

Comment: I've improved the LaTeX formatting on your question; apologies if I changed your intended meaning in any way. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190535/how-to-solve-real-analysis/190729#190729).

Comment: @karanveersingh what's the book name?

Comment: my teacher asked me to prove $π/4=1/2+1/1*3−1/3*5+1/5*7−1/7*9$
when $n=1$ for this same problem. But I can't yet.

Comment: This is solved. When $x=π/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\sin$ term comes form $n=1$ you can't devide by zero.

mh I calculated again, your $\cos(x)$ terms are right, there shouldn't be a $-$ in the denominator

For $$\int_0^\pi \sin(x) e^{inx}\, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1+ e^{i \pi n}}{1-n^2}$$
we have to check the case $n=1$ seperate as we can't devide by zero.

The case $n=1$ give
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \exp(x)\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{i \pi }{2}$$

Comment: How do I introduce a sine term for n = 1 case? 

Is my answer incomplete or am I just missing simplification?

Comment: @KaranveerSingh your work was incomplete

Comment: When computing the result with the real fourier series, how did you integrate $\frac {1}{\pi} sin(x)cos(nx)dx$ from 0 to $\pi$

Comment: with the good old trigonometric theorems, $2 \sin(\alpha)\cdot \cos(\beta)= \sin(\alpha+\beta) + \sin(\alpha-\beta)$

Comment: AH! I keep forgetting those.

Comment: I think it's beatiful to see them in the denominator which is $\frac{1}{(1+k)\cdot (1-k)}$

Comment: @KaranveerSingh If you like an answer you can upvote them.

Comment: @KaranveerSingh aren't sin(x) and cos(nx) perpendicular?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, $C_1$ is a special case and you need to handle separately as

$$ C_1 = \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) e^{-ix} dx \neq 0. $$

Comment: wouldn't it be $e^{-inx}dx$?

Comment: @KaranveerSingh: I copied your formula. Yes it should be $e^{-inx}$.

Comment: Oh, there was supposed to be one there.  Sorry for that.

Comment: @KaranveerSingh: No problem. Anyways, as I said $C_1$ is a special case. That means you have to handle it separtly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $\phi(t)$ is defined on $-L=-\pi<t<\pi=L$ , the Fourier series can be expressed as shown below :

[image]

The numerical tests of the formula are well consistent with a good accuracy.

On the figure below, small values of $m$ are taken in order to make clear the deviations in case of series limited to not enough terms.

[image]

Comment: Which software you use to plot that? @JJacquelin.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory. Software implemented with "Delphi" from Borland.