# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16k^4 - 1} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{8}\coth(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, fourier-series

I want to prove that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16k^4 - 1} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{8}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
Using the fourier series:
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }-\pi<x<0, \\
\sin(x) & \text{if }0<x<\pi.
\end{cases}$$
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x)+ \frac {2}{\pi}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2n x)}{4n^2 - 1}\right)$$
See: [Fourier series of function $f(x)=0$ if $-\pi<x<0$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ if $0<x<\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324073/fourier-series-of-function-fx-0-if-pix0-and-fx-sinx-if-0x-pi)

So far I have:
$$\phi(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac {2}{\pi}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{4n^2 - 1}\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac {2}{\pi}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2 - 1}\right)$$
Then, using Parsaval's Theorem:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)| =\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac {2}{\pi}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2 - 1}|\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac {2}{\pi}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{|4n^2 - 1|}\right)$$
I ma stuck here.

Comment: Also, how to I do proper | in MathJax?

Comment: \left| and \right| should work.

Comment: I would review Parseval theorem...

Comment: Alternately, start with Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function, let $x=it$ and use the relation between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, then multiply the two expressions and take the logarithm of their product.

Comment: There is a relevant technique at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Parseval's theorem incorrectly. Try another approach: find the Fourier series for $f(x)=\cos \frac{x}{4}$, $-\pi\leq x\leq\pi$ and set there $x=\pi$.